# How can I resolve dependency conflicts in Azure WebJob SDK?

Tags: json, azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying out the Azure WebJob SDK (v 0.3.1). I have packaged everything up and uploaded it, but in the dashboard I get the error:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I understand this to mean that a newer version of `Newtonsoft.Json` is referenced in the app than is referenced in the WebJob SDK. However, I have tried adding a dependency binding redirect to the `app.config` associated with the exe, but this does not change the error.  I suspect that config is not being used at all. I have the following binding direct in both `job.blah.exe.config` and `web.config`:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Newtonsoft.Json is v6.0.0.0 in both projects.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried to reproduce the issue you are reporting but I cannot. Can you please let me know what version of each package you have in `packages.config` and what binding redirects you have in `app.config`?

Comment: The version of Newtonsoft.Json I have, both in the web app and the webjob project is 6.0.0.0.  I will update the question with the binding...

Comment: I was able to resolve by removing the redirects and forcing the webapp and webjob to use NewtonSoft.Json 4.5.1.  A comment here makes me thing that it's in the GAC on the Azure WebSite OS and there's nothing I can do about it... http://www.newtonsoft.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support

Comment: I'm running Json.Net v6 in a web-job, and binding redirects (along with other settings) are picked up from `app.config`. Are you sure this file is deployed next to the `.exe` file?

Comment: Well, it gets renamed to someapp.exe.config, but yes, it resides alongside the exe (ie is in the zip file I upload).  Note that I only get this at runtime _when something invokes JSON.NET code_.  If you reference JSON.NET, but don't do anything with it, I don't think you would get this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with the Azure WebJob SDK.  I got it working using the answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647471/3832947)

```
  UnInstall-Package Microsoft.Azure.Jobs

  Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Services.Client -Version 5.6.0
  
  Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.0.5

  Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Jobs
```

Comment: @jasonAller added relevant pieces of answer.

Comment: This did, in fact fix the issue, and I guess is 'best' for now.  I'm still not 100% clear what I would do if there was some need for JSON.NET v 6...

Comment: @jasonAller could someone explain how this deserves a negative vote after I took the time to address your feedback in addition to providing a resolution to the question?

Comment: @Daniel this is caused by references in MSFT's Web Jobs SDK which I can't directly resolve. The workaround is all I've got for now.  Glad it helped.