# Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData' when accessing Azure Storage during development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-storage

I have created a simple C# application at visual studio and I try to run that from my local machine. I have visual studio 2013. However, when I try to run the program, I get the exception: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral

I have also tried the solution mentioned here:[Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.OData Version=5.2.0.0 error in Azure Cloud Worker Role using Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908384/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-odata-version-5-2-0-0-error-in-az)

That is to add the following at my config file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

But it still didn't work. I do not know if I should change anything at the versions of that text.

The line that throws the exception is:

```
    CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

I have also downloaded the package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/ as mentioned at [Missing Microsoft.Data.Services.Client version 5.6 on Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457846/missing-microsoft-data-services-client-version-5-6-on-azure-websites). However the installer informed me that I already have the version 5.6.1.0 of the file and nothing happens.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)   Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage   StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation operation, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
       at UserConsoleProject2.Program.connectionAzureStorage() in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UserConsoleProject2\UserConsoleProject2\Program.cs:line 42
       at UserConsoleProject2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UserConsoleProject2\UserConsoleProject2\Program.cs:line 419   InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException
       HResult=-2146234304
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
       Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
       FileName=Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/UserConsoleProject2/UserConsoleProject2/bin/Debug/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
=== LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UserConsoleProject2\UserConsoleProject2\bin\Debug\UserConsoleProject2.exe.Config LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/UserConsoleProject2/UserConsoleProject2/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Data.OData.DLL. WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableOperationHttpWebRequestFactory.BuildRequestForTableOperation(Uri uri, UriQueryBuilder builder, IBufferManager bufferManager, Nullable`1 timeout, TableOperation operation, Boolean useVersionHeader, OperationContext ctx, TablePayloadFormat payloadFormat, String accountName)
            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.<>c__DisplayClass18.<RetrieveImpl>b__15(Uri uri, UriQueryBuilder builder, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean useVersionHeader, OperationContext ctx)
            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ProcessStartOfRequest[T](ExecutionState`1 executionState, String startLogMessage)
            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
       InnerException:
```

How can I make my program run?

Comment: Where are you trying to run the program - on your local machine while developing/testing or actually on Azure?  Does it work in one and not the other?

Comment: Pleas post the code associated where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: What is your target framework in the Application properties?  It should not be one that ends with Client Profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.OData Version=5.2.0.0 error in Azure Cloud Worker Role using Table Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908384/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-odata-version-5-2-0-0-error-in-az)

Comment: @JimMSDN I have updated my question to include the line that produces the error. In addition I run the program from my local machine

Comment: @JimMSDN Yeah, I saw that question when I posted mine. I have the same problem, but the solution mentioned there does not work for me while it worked for the OP there

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem. I got it to work by making sure I had the following libary versions installed from NuGet:

```
Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Configuration 2.0.0.0
Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Storage 4.1.0.0
Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.1.0
Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.1.0
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.1.0
System.Spatial 5.6.1.0
```

I then changed my app.config to contain the following:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note that the referenced assemblies are version 5.6.1.0 while the app.config refers to 5.6.0.0. I don't know why this works.

Comment: This worked for me, along with making sure Microsoft.Data.* dlls were at 5.6.0.0

Comment: The difference is that one is the package version the other assembly version.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Visual Studio forgets to copy binaries from dependency projects. So, manually delete `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuild target project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the following part of code missing in your web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: This is the solution that exist here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908384/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-odata-version-5-2-0-0-error-in-az?rq=1 but it mentions older versions than the version than the OP has

Comment: Thanks Ondipuli. I have tried that, but I couldn't make it work. Maybe if I change something at the versions will work. But I do not know what exactly.

Comment: You can try this. Try to reinstall Storage client libraries via Nuget. It will install the relevant dlls by default. Go to Visual Studio ->Tools-> Libarary Packet Manager - >Packet Manager Console -> PM> Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage

Comment: Can you try to change the version, by replacing the existing dependent assembly by this one  <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>

Comment: I think, there is one more dependent assembly you have to add in your web.config to  make this work. <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a .net core2.0 webjob, and could not find the answer (here or a blog etc) (this was not it, this would maybe work for pre core, but it gave me the clue)... but when I upgrade my Microsoft.Azure.webjobs and .Extentions to beta4 3.0.0 it resolved the issue - if this saves someone from 2 days of hell, great.